# Troubles with cursor snapping

Tags: modeling

I want to snap cursor to the center of selected face of the cube. I can do that by separating the face from the cube, setting it's orgin to it's geometry and than snapping cursor to selected separated face. Is there a shorter way? Can it be as easy as snapping cursor to a vertex?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snapping also works in edit mode. Select the face, then use  <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd> and choose cursor to selected. Works for faces, edges and vertices.